# fathers chair gadol hador

Tags: rabbis, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I was quite curious on what happens if a rabbi comes to your house and lets say your fathers chair was there and it would be nice for the rabbi to have it. If your father is not there, are u able to give over the chair to the rabbi? Even though your father isn't there, can u still let him sit there? and even more, What happens if it was the gedolei hador? What happens if ur father is a rabbi?

Comment: Is it ever prohibited to let someone else sit in your father's chair?

Comment: @DoubleAA its probably not respectful